# Node.js: How to validate encoding?

Tags: node.js, encoding

I was expecting that Node would throw an exception if I pass a wrong base64 string to the [Buffer.from](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_str_encoding) method, but instead it returns a partial conversion. For instance, the following:

```
var b = Buffer.from('This? It\'s clearly not base64!', 'base64');
```

Has the same effect of:

```
var b = Buffer.from('This', 'base64');
```

Is there a way to validate base64 or hex encoding in Node?

Comment: Actually, the only thing invalid in that string is the last `!`. Everything else is valid base64. Remember: in base64 whitespace is valid but is skipped in the decoding. The second string `This` is 100% valid base64

Comment: @slebetman Thanks, I edited the sample to be more accurate.